# Python - Let a user input a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, user-input

I´m currently writing a test script for a custom python console. My question is, how do I let the user input a already defined function?

Example: My script gets an input from the user. It detects, that its a line of code, therefore executes it.

Does anyone know how I can implement this as code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the user be able to "input a[n] already defined function" (the function is defined _in your code_) or to input their own implementation of some function (like `lambda a, b: a + b`)?

Comment: Please add a minimal example of what your input and desired output would be

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are already defined I would suggest you define a dictionary of choices to pick from.

It's typically a very bad idea to let a user input and execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the `eval()` function which is builtin. it takes the string parameter and executes the parsed string. For example:

```
x = 1

print(eval('x + 1'))
>>>2
```